# how to integrate a browser in electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am recently developing a semiautomatic web content extractor using electron. In my design, this app can display a web, allowing user to select some DOM content in this web, and automatically extract useful data inside these DOM.

But I don't know how to display a web inside electron app. I tried using a `<iframe/>` to show the web, but when the `X-Frame-Options` header is set to `sameorigin`, it won't be display in an iframe.

Is there any other way to integrate a web inside an electron app? Especially, I need to listen the click event inside the integrated web, and I also need to access the DOM from this web.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window

Answer (score 0):

You can easily spawn a new `BrowserWindow` for any web url and can run a preload script with your code that you want to run on the other web page.

That would be the code that you need to scrape the content (and send it to you main process via ipc) and the code that would attach your click event listeners.